# What does this command of class mean in kotlin?

Tags: java, class, kotlin

I'll be direct, my question is what mean ::class in kotlin? I also want to know what means ::class.java.
I see a lot of this commands but i never understand what this really mean. E.g: MyClass::class.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web search for [`"::class" in kotlin`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%3A%3Aclass%22%20in%20kotlin) finds [**Class references**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references) in the [Reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) chapter of the [**Kotlin Language Guide**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/):

> The most basic reflection feature is getting the runtime reference to a Kotlin class. To obtain the reference to a statically known Kotlin class, you can use the *class literal* syntax:
>
> ```kotlin
> val c = MyClass::class
> ```
>
> The reference is a value of type [KClass](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html).
>
> Note that a Kotlin class reference is not the same as a Java class reference. To obtain a Java class reference, use the `.java` property on a KClass instance.